# Using latex in Anki

Tags: latex, anki

How do you set up Anki to use Latex equations on its cards? I would love to be able to use Anki cards to review maths definitions, theorems, proofs etc.

I really hope someone in this community knows how to achieve this. I have scoured the Internet to no avail, but I cannot find any good guides on setting this up.

Here is the [Anki app](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/anki/)

Here are some things I have tried to decipher:

http://www.hyperbolics.caths.cam.ac.uk/links/latexankisetup.php
http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~zibrowiu/LatexNoteImporter/

The answer should include how Latex is set-up within the Anki app itself, as well as any Latex set-up that is purely Latex specific (if any).

Comment: What is Anki? Can you provide a link or a more detailed example?

Comment: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/anki/ and http://ankisrs.net/ . It is a flash card program.

Comment: The link you gave claims that Anki can do this. What have you tried and how did it fail? Did you read the [relevant documentation](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#latex-support)?

Comment: I know. Basically you need to get Anki to 'understand'  latex. It is not the writing of the latex that is a problem. I hope I don't seem like I am just being lazy here, but genuinely I have been unsuccessful at finding the way to do this. I haven't found documentation with clear instructions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. **Install LaTeX**

   - TeX Live: Essential programs and files support in your system

     ```
     sudo apt-get install texlive-base
     ```

   **or**

   - TeX Live: metapackage pulling in all components of TeX Live

     ```
     sudo apt-get install texlive-full
     ```
2. **Start Anki**

   [image]
3. **Create a deck**

   Click the button <kbd>Create Deck</kbd> in the lower part of the main window and create a deck, in my example `Math`

   [image]
4. **Click the field <kbd>Add</kbd> below the menu bar…**

   …and add some LaTeX, eg

   ```
   Does the sum below converge?

   [latex]\begin{displaymath}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\end{displaymath}[/latex]
   ```

   [image]

   and click <kbd>Add</kbd> and <kbd>Close</kbd>
5. **Click the entry <kbd>Math</kbd>**

   [image]

   and you will see this

   [image]
6. **Click <kbd>Study Now</kbd>…**

   …and you have your LaTeX

   [image]

<sub>Source and more information [here](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#latex-on-web/mobile)</sub>

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu 16.04, it was enough to install `texlive-base` and `dvipng`:  `sudo apt-get install texlive-base dvipng`
(`dvipng` is installed automatically with the `texlive-full` package, but this is way larger that `texlive-base`)

Comment: I've tried the above above but it does not work for me. For some reason I get the following error: Error executing latex. Generated file: /tmp/anki_temp/tmp.tex Have you installed latex and dvipng? My system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I managed to find a solution. This thread has been useful https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240255, in particular sudo fmtutil-sys --all command which installed pdflatex.fmt. Now it's working.

Comment: Geosphere's fmtutil-sys didn't work for me. What worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 was to `apt install texlive-latex-recommended dvipng` (base wasn't enough, but recommended was).